# Up-to-date sentence readability algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

I'm working on an algorithm for estimating [sentence difficulty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readability_test), but the methods that I have found seem to be too old to take advantage of what modern computers can do.

The algorithms in use today were mostly developed around 40 to 60 years ago. [Flesch-Kincaid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests) is the most popular and is still used as the standard for documents by the Department of Defense and many states and businesses.  I have looked at Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level, Gunning Fog Index, SMOG Index, Fry Readability Formula, and Coleman-Liau Index.

I have decided to use the Automated Readability Index:

```
ARI = 4.71 * (characters / words) + .5 * (words / sentences) - 21.43;
```

It seems to me that it would not be difficult to assign a value to each word based on Corpus-based word frequency lists and then work these values into the old readability formula.
This could be done for the first 1000 to 5000 most frequent words.
Also it would probably be effective to make separate lists for some different kinds of words and parts of speech.  The presence of conjunctions would definitely be a sign of sentence complexity.

Are there any formulas for doing this?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I made a demo containing also  ARI a couple of years ago: http://lt3.hogent.be/en/demos/readability/. Enter a text and you get all the scores. Click on the links in the results to get documentation about our implementation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is more concerned with available readability metrics possessing certain performance features rather than a specific question of how they are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you see a hard coded constant in a machine learning formula, be suspicious...

The numbers in the [Automated Readability Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_readability_index) represent a model that was suitable to the data set used to build it and the features chosen to represent it.
Other than the suitability, I assume that being a common measure, calibrated into school grade is another benefit.

Your idea of adding word frequency into the readability sounds like a great feature.  After all, a single unfamiliar word in a sentence of simple grammar might turn it into unreadable.

You should choose the way you would like to represent the sentence given the word frequencies. Examples might be the the probability of the entire sentence, number of uncommon words, minimal frequency, etc.

Then you should build a dataset and learn the parameters of the model form it. The most straight forward way will be to use a dataset of sentences manually labeled for readability.  However, building such a data set seems to be very time consuming.

You can bypass this problem by using some sources whose readability level is known in general, and label the sentences readability according to the source. 
For example, sentences from [simple English wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) should be more readable than those from wikipedia. Other sources of a common readability levels can the wall street journal and web forums. 
Do some manual labeling to these sentences in order to align and calibrate you readability value.

By using this technique you tradeoff the label accuracy for the amount of labels. Since it was proven that machine learning can be done in the presence of white noise and even malicious errors, such a tradeoff is usually beneficial.